# Storage Access Framework not showing external storage device

Tags: android

I am currently using the storage access framework to allow my users to create/delete documents.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Some of my users (a small percentage) are complaining though that their external storage device does not show up in the dialog screen.

I've already set the hidden EXTRA.

intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);

which is why my other users (the majority of them) can see the external storage.  I am just wondering if there is some other EXTRA I need to set for the other users to see their external storage.

**Edit:**

Here's how I create the intent I use for the storage access framework.

```
private static final String MIME_TYPE = "*/*";
private static final String EXTRA_SHOW_ADVANCED = "android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED";

private static Intent buildIntent() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType(MIME_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_ADVANCED, true);
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: You know that on most devices the user first has to go to the menu to enable show devices? Why dont you mention this option?

Comment: Please show the complete code for the intent used.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't rely on hidden constant values. This is a best effort stuff. Don't be surprised if it doesn't always work.

Vendors reserve their rights to modify Android code base, as long as their modifications don't break any [CTS](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/) test, or GTS test if they would like to preload Google Service Framework. Hidden constants and API's usually are not protected by any CTS test so vendors might choose to remove them.

Google also reserves the right to remove any hidden API in future releases.